# Error in function 'distanceTransform' - Python, using OpenCV (3.4.9)

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use distance transform to contours, but I am getting an error:

```
out = cv2.distanceTransform(mask, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.9) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/distransform.cpp:724: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function 'distanceTransform'
```

And this is my code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

pathToThePhoto = 'labrador.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(pathToThePhoto)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
mask = cv2.drawContours(gray, [c], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2) #Edit: Changed from img to gray

out = cv2.distanceTransform(mask, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)

cv2.imshow("distance-transform", out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

labrador.jpg:

[image]

Result after Edit:

[image]

It doesn't look like the correct result, or yes?

Comment: You need to pass a grayscale image(or a picture that has only 1 channel) to the function.

Comment: @FarhoodET please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the output of `cv2.distanceTransform` is of type `np.float32`.
You need to **normalize** `out` to range [0, 1] before showing `out`.

See OpenCV [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html):

> Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
>   so we can visualize and threshold it
>   `cv.normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, cv.NORM_MINMAX)`
>   `cv.imshow('Distance Transform Image', dist)`

Here is the code:

```
import cv2
import imutils

pathToThePhoto = 'labrador.jpg'

img = cv2.imread(pathToThePhoto)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100 , 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
mask = cv2.drawContours(gray, [c], -1, 255, 2) #Edit: Changed from img to gray

out = cv2.distanceTransform(mask, distanceType=cv2.DIST_L2, maskSize=5)

# Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
# so we can visualize and threshold it
out = cv2.normalize(out, out, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

cv2.imshow("distance-transform", out)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`out`:
[image]

I am not sure if this is your intended result.
You are applying the Distance Transform on the image with the puppy.

`mask`:
[image]